# Odd behavior by #define

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have this code in C++:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int const foo = 1;
int const bar = 0;

#define foo bar
#define bar foo

int main()
{
  std::cout << foo << std::endl;
  std::cout << bar << std::endl;
}
```

It produces this output:

```
bash-3.2$ ./a.out
1
0
```

I do not understand why this is the output.

Comment: Why are you doing this? :(

Comment: He wants to embed this in some random header file and make someones life a living hell.

Comment: Using a macro to re-define a reserved word gives undefined behavior. Not much more to understand.

Comment: That, and circularly-referential macros.

Comment: my guess would be you are undoing the first define with the second define and making no change at all :\

Comment: I replaced the true/false stuff as I believe it's irrelevant to the question and is only fueling downvotes. Rollback the edit if you disagree.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Macros will never expand recursively.

When you write `foo`, it first expands to `bar`, and then since `bar` is a macro it expands back to `foo`. While `foo` is a macro, because macros can't be recursive it will not be expanded. And then evaluating `foo` yields its value: 1.

The same goes for `bar`.

See this: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Self_002dReferential-Macros.html#Self_002dReferential-Macros

And *ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E) 16.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement* section of the standard. (see comments for more details)

Comment: @phonetagger Do you have a citation for that? Anyway, it's clearly more than two passes as triple expansions work. This other contains some details: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Please cite ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E) 16.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement.  Oh, wait, I just did that for you.  You might mention that the macro replacements continue until such time as the original macro name might occur, at which point further macro expansions cease.  Thus foo "expands" to bar, and bar "expands" back to foo, at which point the process stops.

Comment: @phonetagger Thanks for looking it up! I'll take your word for it as I don't have a copy of the standard on this computer.

Comment: ...Actually it was Robᵩ that looked it up.  But I read it & you're right.